# Return Array index and increment at the same time

Tags: java, android, kotlin

How does Java, Kotlin, and Android handle returning an Array value at a given index while incrementing the index value?

```
int[] someArray = new int[5];
int index = 0;
int result;

result = someArray[index++];
```

Which index would be passed to the result? Will it increment `index` first, then pass it to `someArray[1]`, or will it pass the original value of `index` to `someArray[0]` and then increment `index`?

Comment: When faced with such questions, it's just as quick to try it out yourself, e.g. using an online tool such as [ideone](http://ideone.com/)

Comment: ah cool...when i program in python, i test out code right from terminal. not as easy to do that in android, i'll try out that online tool next time, thanks.

Comment: @godMode try [IDEdroid Free](https://market.android.com/details?id=com.idedroidfree)

Answer (score 20, accepted):

See: Java documentation, *[Assignment, Arithmetic, and Unary Operators](http://download.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/nutsandbolts/op1.html)*:

> The code result++; and ++result; will both end in result being incremented by one. The only difference is that the prefix version (++result) evaluates to the incremented value, whereas the postfix version (result++) evaluates to the original value.

So you'll get `someArray[0]`.

Answer (score 6):

`index++` returns `index` and then increments by 1.  So it will do `result = someArray[0]` and then set `index` to 1.

In contrast, `++index` would do the increment and then pass the incremented value.  So if you wanted `result` set to `someArray[1]` in the above code, you would use `++index`.

As someone else said, please don't use this kind of syntax.  Instead, please write

```
index++;
result = someArray[index];
```

Answer (score 4):

In Java and similar languages, using `index++` only increment the value after the expression has been evaluated.  If you want to increment before using the variable, use `++index`.

In this case, it will use the original value of `index` to obtain `result`, and then increase its value to 1.

Answer (score 3):

It will pass `someArray[0]` and then increment `index`

It is not dependent from android, the general rule is:

index++ means evaluates index and then increment it, while ++index is increment then evaluate

Answer (score 1):

1.) Avoid doing this sort of thing, in fact with code I review I ask people to never do this.

Not specifically using ++, but the fact you're doing it as part of evaluating something else.  Generally it won't cost the compiler any extra to have that increment as a separate statement, and putting it inline like that means the next person coming along has to take a second and evaluate the increment themselves.

I know it's minor, and it's a little nitpicky, but stuff like this costs extra time during code review, it's easy to miss while scanning, etc.   And it saves you nothing but a few extra keystrokes, which when compared against code clairity and readability is not worth it IMO.

2) You will get someArray[0], and after moving on to the next line, you will have your index incremented.

Comment: ++ is a pretty common operation. If you're developing software that someone else is going to maintain, then pre/postincrementing is usually something you can expect them to know. I agree that you shouldn't usually do this, but that's  terrible reason.

Comment: Agreed, expanded on my reason slightly and clairified that i'm not against pre/post incrementing, just with doing it inline on other operations.   Unless there's a specific compiler reason to do so in a given case, you are trading keystrokes for clairity/readability which is a terrible habit to be in.